# Youtube Data API get subscriber list by channel id

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

is there a way to get a list of followers from a channel with the channel id? I found this snippt, but it's only for the subsciber count.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=<channel_id>&key=<api_key>
```

Dose anyone has experience with that?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list), there is a filter method that can be use to retrieve a complete list of subscribers which does not return a particular order and will not limit the number of subscribers that can be retrieved.

> **mySubscribers** *boolean*
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly
> authorized request. Set this parameter's value to true to retrieve a
> feed of the subscribers of the authenticated user in no particular
> order.